# What am I missing for my prime number detector to not append true and false?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
const isPrime = (num) =>  {
    

    for(let i = 1, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++){
        num % i === 0 ? d.append('number is prime') : d.append(false)
        
    }
    
}
isPrime(1)
```

I seem to be missing something in my prime number detector as my turnary operator keeps returning both true and false if a prime number is passed to the function.

Comment: Using a ternary if that way is a ***terrible*** idea / practice. Use a regular if - and you should really not do anything if the numbers do not divide, just move to the next iteration.

Comment: You're iterating over a bunch of factors and append every outcome. The first test is against 1, and every integer % 1 is 0.

Comment: What is `d`? JavaScript uses `push()` to add to an array, not `append()`.

Comment: What you need to do instead is start the loop at 2, *return* false inside the loop if for any i the remainder is 0, then return true after the loop: https://jsfiddle.net/4grubokj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in the code

1. You can't start the loop 1. Every number is divisible by 1, so this will always be true.
2. A number is prime if it is divisible by *no* number less than its square root. You must finish the entire for loop before concluding that it is prime.
3. You should exit the for loop with `break` or `return` after you find the result. If you don't, it will keep appending results until all numbers in the loop are checked.

Here is a slightly modified version to show the points explained above:

```
const isPrime = (num) => {
    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        // if it has a divisor, we know it is not prime
        if (num % i === 0) {
            d.append('false')
            // we want to stop the for loop and exit the function
            return
        }
    }
    // if the loop concluded without returning, the number is prime
    d.append('number is prime')
}
```

As a suggestion, I'd also recommend separating the logic from your presentation by having isPrime return true or false, and separately handle your output display.

You can also make this more efficient by checking num === 2 separately and then skipping over all even divisors since 2 is the only prime number divisible by an even divisor.

All together, here is how I'd suggest to improve the code:

```
const isPrime = (num) => {
    if (num < 2) return false; // 1 is not prime
    if (num === 2) return true; // 2 is prime
    // can skip by 2 since all even numbers after two are not prime
    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i += 2) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

const appendPrime = (num) => {
    d.append(isPrime(num) ? 'number is prime' : 'false');
}

appendPrime(4)
```

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. I ended up figuring out a neat short way to go about it last night. Thanks for the answer!